# C++: Qt 5.3 fails to display UTF-8 character

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to display a unicode character (Euro sign) on a button using Qt and C++ in Visual Studio 2013. I tried the following code:

```
_rotateLeftButton->setText("\u20AC");
```

and

```
_rotateLeftButton->setText("€");
```

and

```
_rotateLeftButton->setText(QString::fromUtf8("\u20AC"));
```

and

```
_rotateLeftButton->setText(QString::fromUtf8("€"));
```

However, all of those lines result in the following:

[image: Character can not be displayed]

All my code files are UTF-8 encoded, except for the moc files (.cxx). For whichever reason the moc executable does not generate them using unicode. Yet I was not able to get this unicode symbol displayed correctly. I also tried setting another font than the default one withouth success. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please try `QChar(0x20AC)`? And maybe a different font? Another try is to do the same with a `QLineEdit`, and copy-paste the text to somewhere else to check whether or not it is an Euro sign which could not be displayed.

Comment: Thank you! Using QChar it works. I only wonder why.

Comment: Maybe your code file isn't really saved as UTF8, or your compiler doesn't read it as intended... I usually avoid non-ascii characters in any source file (except comments). Regarding `\u20AC`, I simply don't know how exactly this is being interpret. But with `QChar`, you're on the safe path.

Comment: You need to save your files **with BOM** for VS to recognize UT8.

Comment: Thank you, now the code samples where I put the € directly into the code work, but the ones using \u20AC still don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
QString::fromUtf8("€")
```

Will work if the file really is handled as UTF-8. As @n.m. commented, VS requires some help from a faux-BOM to ensure this.

```
QString::fromUtf8("\u20AC")
```

`\u` doesn't make sense in a byte string literal. You could spell it using `\x` byte escapes for the UTF-8 encoded version:

```
QString::fromUtf8("\xE2\x82\xAC")
```

Or use a wide string literal:

```
QString::fromWCharArray(L"\u20AC")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that your answers are correct. What exactly does `\x` do? And what about standard std::strings? Is it possible to define a unicode std::string?