# QTextEdit unicode QString not working

Tags: windows, qt, unicode, qtextedit

I'm trying to write method which prints messages in `QTextEdit`, using custom font (Veteran Typewriter). This font which I use supports Unicode but when I use it in my application, all characters like 'ą', 'ę', 'ż' and other polish characters are not shows correctly (all are replaced by �). Do you have any idea why? How to force use Unicode? (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community + Qt5 Add-on, on Windows 10 x64 and project is defined as x64 too).

My code:

```
void QtCubic::QtCStartScreen::sendMessage(QString message) {
    if (log.toPlainText().length() != 0) {
        log.insertPlainText("\n");
    }
    log.insertPlainText(message);
}
```

And this is how I send example meassage:

```
splashScreen.sendMessage("Zażółć gęślą jaźń");
```

Comment: what is the result of `QString::fromUtf8("Zażółć gęślą jaźń")`

Comment: Duplicate: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754246/3637404)

Comment: the result looks like Za���� g��l� ja��. I found linked question earlier but that solution don't work for me. Even if I use `log.setText(QString::fromUtf8("Zażółć gęślą jaźń")` the result is the same.

Comment: what about `QString::fromStdWString(std::wstring(L"Zażółć gęślą jaźń"))`

Comment: what is the project character set ?  `right click project -> properties -> config properties->General->Character Set`

Comment: So, Character Set in project properties does nothing but this freaky and funny form with `QString::fromStdWString(std::wstring(L"Zażółć gęślą jaźń"))` works awesome. Thank you for help. I have one extra question, cause I'm just curious, whats a difference between "Unicode Character Set" and "Multi-Byte Character Set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Unicode string literals in Qt, you should be using the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro.

In other words, your code would look like this:

```
splashScreen.sendMessage(QStringLiteral("Zażółć gęślą jaźń"));
```